# .any()/.all() when checking array elements in list

Tags: python

Hi I'm currently stuck trying to solve this problem:

```
a = [array([1,3]),array([11,3])]
b = [array([1,7]),array([1,9])]
c = [[array([1,3]),array([11,3])], [array([2,6]),array([9,9])]]
if b not in c:
    c.append(b)
if a not in c:
    c.append(a)
```

I'm keep getting an error message telling me that I have to correct my code using `any()` or `all()`. How do I check if an array element is already in the list or not using `any()`/`all()`?

Comment: Why does that cause an error message?

Comment: Is array a function?  What should array([1,3]) return?

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that we can copy-paste and run. Please include the exact error message you receive, including any traceback. see [mcve] for more info.

Comment: The missing error would be ```ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()```

Comment: Is `array` something from `numpy`?

Comment: yeah, array is from numpy, and I get the error message as the one Ben posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in any case, here's a starting point so you can continue experimenting by yourself:

```
a = [[1, 3], [11, 3]]
b = [[1, 7], [1, 9]]
c = [[[1, 3], [11, 3]], [[2, 6], [9, 9]]]

print a in c
print b in c
print all([a in c, b in c])
print any([a in c, b in c])
```

This is just a simple example showing how to use any & all.